# Find all subscripts of a matrix

Tags: r

Is there a quick way to identify all the subscripts of a matrix, independent of its contents?

for example:

```
dat <- matrix(runif(20),nrow=5)

which(!is.na(dat),arr.ind=TRUE)
which(dat!="foo",arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Will work if no values of the matrix are NA or "foo".  But is there an easy way to get these subscripts for all matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid()` is perfectly sufficient, but here's a nifty alternative:

```
 matrix(c(row(dat), col(dat)), ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expand.grid(row = seq(nrow(dat)), col = seq(ncol(dat)))
#   row col
#1    1   1
#2    2   1
#3    3   1
#4    4   1
#5    5   1
#6    1   2
#7    2   2
#8    3   2
#9    4   2
#10   5   2
#11   1   3
#12   2   3
#13   3   3
#14   4   3
#15   5   3
#16   1   4
#17   2   4
#18   3   4
#19   4   4
#20   5   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you mean by all subscripts, but this will create a data.frame containing all combinations of row and column indices

```
expand.grid(sapply(dim(dat), seq_len))
```

Comment: I suppose I should have said "subscripts for every element of any matrix"